# Behaviour of the ? quantifier when applying to (\b) in JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have a tiny regex: [`foo(\b)?`](https://regex101.com/r/SvhtaF/1). This was meant to be an experiment to see if I can deduce the existence of the boundary just by checking whether the first group was matched (and resulting in an empty string) or not.

I tried this with some languages: [PHP](https://onecompiler.com/php/3zczp4rd2)/[Python](https://onecompiler.com/python/3zcznwtnv)/[Java](https://onecompiler.com/java/3zczpqm9f)/[C#](https://onecompiler.com/csharp/3zczs3e9w)/[Rust](https://rustexp.lpil.uk/)<sup>Input manually</sup>. All of them behave as expected: An empty string for the first match and `null`/`None`/nothing for the second.

<sub>I can't figure out how to write a proper snippet in Go and C++, but regex101 says Go goes with those; I'm unsure about C++.</sub>

However, this is not the case with JS, as it outputs `undefined` for group 1 in both matches against `foo food`.

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

console.log(...'foo food'.matchAll(/foo(\b)?/g));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Yet, `(\b)` without `?` *does* capture an empty string.

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

console.log(...'foo food'.matchAll(/foo(\b)/g));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Considering that `?` is greedy, shouldn't `(\b)` always match and capture an empty string after the first `foo`, as with other languages? What are the alternatives?

I can reproduce this in both NodeJS and Chrome (V8) as well as Firefox (Gecko), so this is probably a quirk rather than a bug.

Comment: This does not depend on `\b`, you get the same behavior using `foo()?`, so whenever you ask to match an optional empty string.

Comment: Possibly related: unlike for all the other languages, in JavaScript `foo(d*?)?` matches the whole word `food` instead of just `foo`.

Comment: Interesting. It seems that `?` as well as `*` and `{0,n}` (quantifiers that allow 0 repetitions) either requires the group to have *some* content or fail altogether. For example, the second group in [`foo((?=(.)))?`](https://regex101.com/r/NVIjAb/1) was never matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in both the questions and the comments, this is a quirk. I don't know why nor how, but I have found an alternative: `foo(?:(\b)|)`. Group 1 results in an empty string if the first branch matched and nothing otherwise, effectively disabling this strange behaviour of `?`.

```js
[...'foo food'.matchAll(/foo(?:(\b)|)/g)]

// [0: 'foo', 1: '']
// [0: 'foo', 1: undefined]
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3VHcKW/1).

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

console.log(...'foo food'.matchAll(/foo(?:(\b)|)/g));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

An empty branch is most oftenly seen as a non-recommended version of `?`,<sup>[citation needed]</sup> but it seems that they have some differences after all, at least in ECMAScript.